# What do those people who wear tefillin all weekday do on Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, rosh-chodesh-new-month

There are people who wear tefillin all day (see related question [When did people stop wearing Tefilin all day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/when-did-people-stop-wearing-tefilin-all-day) and the comments to it.)

For [one or two reasons](http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/563495/jewish/Why-Do-We-Remove-Tefillin-on-Rosh-Chodesh-Before-Musaf.htm) many remove tefillin before Mussaf on Rosh Chodesh.

What do those people who wear tefillin all weekday do on Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: I assume they do the same thing as when they visit the bathroom:  take them off, and put them back on when they're done.  (with mussaf)

Comment: @Jake I assume that is the practice nowadays as well. (I would also assume they were just left on during Musaf back in the day when all-day tefillin was common.)

Comment: Please see the following link: http://www.dinonline.org/2014/05/18/tefillin-all-day-on-rosh-chodesh/ which may help with your question

Comment: @DoubleAA according to the reasons listed here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6247/6893 for taking off tefillin during RC mussaf, they would have still applied back when it was more common for Jewish men to wear tefillin all day.  In fact, one could suggest the possibility that they didn't wear tefillin the whole rest of the day on RC, since it's a mini yom tov (but I have no evidence for that, just a guess.)

Comment: @Jake Yes. But such a practice isn't recorded from that time...

Comment: IIRC The Vilna Gaon used to put them back on after Mussaf - looking for a reliable source before answering. have seen people in JSLM do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mishnah Berurah ([OC 25:60](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=70)), quoting *Ba'er Heiteiv* ([ibid. 22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=70)), (as well as [*Zera Avraham*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9KYvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%A8%22%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3&source=bl&ots=Xz6y-TAJCA&sig=aZeuy0yoq3LeII74CsPQqUtsa0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidz8qv7PrSAhUG3SYKHXM0C5wQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%A8%22%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3&f=false)) quoting *Rameh MiPano* ([Siman 108](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20114&st=&pgnum=269)) writes that he puts them back on immediately after *musaf*. Mishnah Berurah adds, if when removing the *tefilin* before *musaf* he had in mind to put them back on afterwards, he should put them on without saying another *beracha*.